# How can I call a method from another class with integers in it?

Tags: java, class, methods

Basically, I have these two classes:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int units = 0;
        int tenth = 0;
        int hunds = 0;
        int thousands = 0;
        Nums met = new Nums();
        System.out.println("Insert 4-digit number ");
        met.set_nums();
        System.out.println("The number " + num + " in reverse is " + units + tenth + hunds + thousands);
    }
}

public class Nums {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int thousands;
    int hunds;
    int tenths;
    int units;
    public void set_nums(int num, int thousands, int hunds, int tenths, int units) {
        num = in .nextInt();
        thousands = num / 1000;
        hunds = num / 100 - ((num / 1000) * 10);
        tenths = num / 10 - ((num / 100) * 10);
        units = num - ((num / 10) * 10);
    }
}
```

I need to make the program scan the number and then make the operations in the second class so it can put the number in reverse. How can I make the main class call out the integers and show up the numbers after the operation?  I have tried other ways like putting the integers in the first class and the scanner too, but none of these have worked. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does "call out the integers and show up the numbers" mean. Does "call out" mean "read from terminal" and "show up" mean "print"? You seem to have arguments for your `set_nums` method that aren't used. What are they for?

Comment: @sprinter Please explain your edit to the question. Removing an `import` statement is not “formatting”. Why did you add all the spaces, especially the space in `in .nextInt()`?

Comment: The import statement is a necessary part to your code.

Comment: the nums class has a import statement, it just didn't came out when I copied it. What the program needs to do is: scan the number, make the operations, and the result of it has to be assigned to the integers so it's printed in the main class

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your code. Before all, I belive it does not compile (I have not tried), because method set_nums is called without arguments and it is declared to receive 4 int parameters.

Even if you pass the variables in Main class, it will not work, because in Java, arguments are passed by value and changes does not return.

To make that code works, you will need:

1. remove declaration of units, tenth, hunds and thousands from Main class.
2. remove all parameters from set_nums method declaration.
3. print values from your instance on Nums class:

   System.out.println ( "The number " + num + " in reverse is " + met.units
   + met.tenths + met.hunds + met.thousands);

For a better coding style, move Scanner instantiation to the Main class and call nextInt there, passing the scanned number to set_nums.

Comment: Please post a complete copy of the code with your changes included. Another user once asked me to do this, even though my change was very simple; your changes are much more complex.